# Bounded Derivatives and Uniformly Convergent Subsequence

Tags: analysis

Let $\{f_n\}$ be a sequence of $C^\infty$ functions on a compact interval such that for each $k$ there exists $M_k$ such that $f_n^{(k)}\leq M_k$ for all $n$ and $x.$ Prove that there exists a subsequence converging uniformly, together with the derivatives of all orders, to a $C^\infty$ function.

I want to use something like the Arzela-Ascoli Theorem but I'm not sure how to prove boundedness, and what the question mean by "together with the derivatives of all orders?" Could somebody provide a proof?

Answer (score 0):

For each $k$, you can show that $f^{(k)}_n$ has a subsequence which converges uniformly to some continuous function, let's say, $f_k$. Then you can use same diagonal trick as it is in the proof of Arzelà–Ascoli theorem to extract a subsequence from them.

An issue here is that whether $f^{(k)}=f_k$ or not. To see this, you can use uniform convergence and exchange the order of limit and derivative.